# In Ruby, what are the naming conventions for mixins when there is no proper english "<verb>able"?

Tags: ruby, naming-conventions, mixins

Example: I have a `Person` class and a `Role` class. I want to extract the role functionality from both `Role` and `Person` into a mixin. I get two mixins: `Actable` to be included in `Role` and `Adaptable` for `Person`.

I sometimes can't think of a proper english word that fits. In the above example, adaptable  seems more fitting for roles than for people, because roles can be adapted and thus are adaptable. A better name would be *versatile* but that breaks the convention of mixin names with ending in ...able. (It's still an adjective though.)

Other example is when I want to add a module that allows checking, if a Person is allowed to view other persons. How do you find a name for that ending in ...able? `Viewable` seems impropriate, the person that *can be viewed* should be viewable. I stuck to `showable` for now (fitting with the method name in the controller). But then again, it's the Person that *can be shown*, that should be showable not the person that wants to show.

So I guess my question is, **When there is no proper english adjective ending in ...able for a module name, should I choose another adjective that does not end in ...able or should I give it a name that does not quite fit?**

Answer (score 3):

How about a prefix then?

```
CanDoSomethingMoreComplexThanASingleVerb
```

**edit:** While I understand I'm not offering a *convention* per se (thanks arulmr for bringing it up), the `Can` Naming convention to describe something is part of de-facto localised naming standards in many companies, as it allows a more verbose description of the functionality you're trying to mixin. e.g. `CanAct` and `CanBeCastInPlay` are distinct properties using the original author's context of `Person` and `Role` and are easier to percieve and understand than `Actable` and `PlayCastable` or other equivalents.

Bottom line: Don't be constrained by language and conventions alone :)

Answer (score 1):

I tend to go verbose and name modules with a longer description of the code they include; something like:
`PersonRoleFunctionality`

I'll often namespace it too; and file it with other mixins under a directory that applies to the object it was extracted from, so I end up with 
`include Extracts:Person:RoleFunctionality` in the `app\models\extracts\person\` directory